# How to create new HTTP GET If the older is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to check when i have HTTP GET and it's loading, it's waiting for something to happen, and when it happen i want to load NEW HTTP GET, and i want every time the HTTP GET is loaded to appear new HTTP GET. How can this happen , is there some kind of listener for the get or trick ?

**HERE IS SOME KIND OF EXAMPLE**

```
$.get('url', function(data1) {
  // here i want i that get with data1 is loadded, to load a new one, and every time when the get loads, i want to appera new get.
});
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confused of what you want to do. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean jQuery .get():

```
$.get('/url1', function(data1) {
    $.get('/url2', function(data2) {
        ...
    });
});
```

Recursive call:

```
function doGet(prevData)
    $.get('/url1', function(data) {
        // if(conditionToStop) 
        //  return;

        doGet(data);
    });
}

doGet(null);
```

NOTE: Since the function is invoked inside a callback function this is not the same as calling the function inside itself. This is not true recursion.

Comment: this will happen only one time more, not always

Comment: Then create a function and call it recursively

Answer (score 0):

Send the HTTP Get Request to the server and return the Json (store the status of the action).Check the Json value at client side if it is true then send the another request(GET).

For - example

```
$.post(url, sr, function (data) {
  if (typeof data == "object") {
     if (data.Status) {
        // Send another request
     }
     else {
       // Show the Message if action is not completed
      }
  }
  else {
          // Show Error Message
  }
});
```

Comment: Can i do it without sending something with post ? Onli some kinda watching get ?